# Mongodb with golang driver not able to write with timeseries collection error: Document failed validation

Tags: mongodb, go, time-series

```golang
db := client.Database("testDB")
jsonSchema := bson.M{
    "bsonType": "object", 
    "properties": bson.M{
        "timeseries": bson.M{
            "timeField": "Ts",
            "granularity": "seconds"
        }
    }
}
validator := bson.M{
    "$jsonSchema": jsonSchema,
}
opts := options.CreateCollection().SetValidator(validator)
_ = db.CreateCollection(context.TODO(), "eureka", opts)
eurekaCollection := db.Collection("eureka")
```

When I try to write into this collection which is defined as above I get an error which says,

```
write exception: write errors: [Document failed validation: {"failingDocumentId": {"$oid":"61dab0b26e96a2a5878007e1"},"details": {"operatorName": "$eq","specifiedAs": {"timeseries": {"granularity": "seconds","timeField": "Ts"}},"reason": "field was missing"}}]
exit status 1
```

Can someone please point out what I am missing here?

Answer (score 0):

As per your question, I can get following info,
"Document failed validation"
"reason": "field was missing"

You need to [Expose the reason an operation fails document validation](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-20547).